# Keyboard layout issues using Ubuntu 12.04 in ssh via X11 for mac

Tags: 12.04, keyboard-layout, macosx, x11

I just upgraded from 10.04 LTS to 12.04 LTS on my server (DELL Intel XEON). By SSH login from my mac (OS X Lion) everything is fine (no issues with command lines) but when I open a window through X11, the keyboard layout is now completely messed up. As an owner of a french mac keyboard, I got used to such issues and could deal by guessing the "QUERTY" keys, but this time it's worse.

To fix it, I tried:

1/

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

=> no effect

2/

```
sudo gnome-control-center
```

then change the keyboard settings, however adding a couple of keyboard layouts did not change anything.

I feel there is something to do with the X11 forwarding.
Any hints?

Thanks

Comment: I eventually fixed my problem, what I did exactly is:

    1/ check the "Follow system keyboard layout" and
      "Enable key equivalent under X11" items in X11 preferences
    2/ quit X11.

Once launching a new window through X11, the keyboard layout was properly handled.

Comment: can you add that as an answer?

Comment: Sure, if that's the way to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually fixed my problem, what I did exactly is:

1. in X11 preferences, I checked the "Follow system keyboard layout" and "Enable key equivalent under X11" items ;
2. quit X11. Once X11 reopened, the keyboard layout was properly handled.

Comment: didn't work for me

Answer (score 4):

In my case, running Yosemite and the latest version of xquartz, going through `ssh -X` to CentOS 6.5 in VMWare Fusion, I could not resolve that problem with switching layouts. US and Russian layouts, in my case. When I started, for example, `gnome-terminal`, I just couldn't switch to my RU language, using any key combinations. So, after half a day of experimenting (I am not really a Linux geek, just kinda "half-of-a-power" user), I found a solution.

Your mac `~/.profile` should look like this:

```
export LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8
```

If you use another language, change `LC_ALL=` for your language in your MacOs.

Then you need to add the following line at the end of your `~/.bash_profile` on your ssh-connected machine (in my case - CentOS 6.5)

```
setxkbmap -rules evdev -model pc104 -layout us,ru
```

This goes correctly, especially for the Russian language. But I am sure your OS must have another collection of  layouts. And, at the end - ensure, than you enabled "Follow system keyboard layout" in *X11*->*Preferences*->*Input* tab.

After these manipulations, forwarded through ssh-X11, the GUI of your application will be able to switch layouts, using your usual MacOS shortcut. In my case, <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. Don't forget to restart X11.

Maybe this will help someone ;-)

P.S.: in this example, I worked only with the Russian layout and keymap, so, again, change parameters for your own!

Comment: Your English is pretty decent, would go without editing, but you should not use slang.

Comment: thank you! i've just wanted to make it understandable as possible :-) and im new here, don't know your rules, so please, sorry

Comment: Detailed and understandable answers is what AskUbuntu needs. Keep them coming.

Comment: thanx, for correcting me in that CODE places, but i hope it is not bad if i was exampling another os than ubuntu? :-)

Comment: Regarding the scope of the question I think it is fine.